# Stack frame in C

Tags: c

If I allocate memory for a `char a[256]`, initialise each element to a different value and pass this to some function:

```
int subFunc(a);
```

how does the stack frame of `subFunc` look?

Does the stack frame contain all the 256 bytes in it or just a pointer to the address of `a` (4 bytes).

If a pointer, then how does it access the data inside the `subFunc` or where is this data available to `subFunc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subFunc` will receive a pointer to `char`, not an array of `char`.  The details of how that pointer is passed will vary with the implementation.  The pointer value may be pushed onto the stack, or it may be passed in a register (gcc 2.96 on Red Hat does the former, while gcc 4.1.2 on SLES 10 does the latter), and that may depend on things like optimization settings, whether you're generating a debug version, etc.  The only way to know for sure how it works on *your* platform is to code it up, build it, and look at the generated machine code.

In most circumstances, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  The exceptions to this rule are when the array expression is an operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize the contents of another array in a declaration.

Given the code

```
char a[256];
...
subFunc(a);
```

the expression `a` in the call to `subFunc` has type "256-element array of `char`"; by the rule above, it is replaced with an expression of type "pointer to `char`" (`char *`) and its value is the address of `a[0]`.

Thus, `subFunc` receives a pointer value, not an array of `char`.

Note that, in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are interpreted as `T *a`; if your prototype for `subFunc` is

```
int subFunc(char a[256])
```

it will be interpreted as

```
int subFunc(char *a)
```

Answer (score 5):

The C language doesn't require a stack based machine. That said, it's likely that on stack based machines a block scope array is allocated on the stack.

You can't pass an array to a function in C. The language specifies that `subFunc(a)` receives a pointer to the first element of `a`. This is exemplified by the fact that the two declarations (or prototypes) `subFunc (char *a)` and `subFunc (char a[])` are treated identical.

Comment: Well, you *can* pass an array - otherwise `subFunc(char a[])` would be meaningless -  But as you note it's passed by reference (= by pointer), rather than value.

Comment: @Roddy No you can't. In C there is *no pass by reference*, only pass by value (pass by reference can be *simulated* with pointers). Even for a parameter declared with `char a[]`, the type of the parameter is *pointer to char*, not *array of char*. The difference becomes obvious once you use `sizeof a` which is different when `a` were an array.

Answer (score 0):

There's only a 4 byte long value(on 32-bit OS) in the stack frame, which's value is the start address of `char a[256]`. Now that we know where the `a` starts, we can access the data.

Comment: Pointers need not be 4 bytes (although 4 bytes is common in 32 bit OS).

Answer (score 0):

The function who called `subFunc()` has `char a[256]`. And that function would be in the stack first. Then, `subFunc()` has been pushed into the stack. But the function who called `subFunc()` need to pass the first address of `a` to `subFunc()`. That will be better if you pass the length of `a` to `subFunc()`.  `subFunc()` should be changed like this:

```
int subFunc(char *, int);
```